# How to implement navigation in static site generator Assemble

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I'd like to build navigation for the static site that I'm generating with [Assemble](http://assemble.io).

Currently, I have a `pages` directory, and several sub-directories within that directory. I'd love to be able to generate some kind of hierarchy or structured navigation like:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/about-us/index.html">About Us</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/about-us/sub-page1.html">Sub Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us/sub-page2.html">Sub Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us/sub-page3.html">Sub Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a preferred way to do this without hard-coding links to all of my pages?

Comment: I think you should use Handlebar template for it and assemble Handlebar helpers are also available https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers